# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/common/flightcontroller/CompassCalibrationState

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dji-sdk

I'd like to read different DJI hardware states using the DJI Android SDK. But for some architectures (Intel), certain DJI classes cannot be resolved using the libraries. This leads to `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

*Affected Devices*: Lenovo Yoga series, Asus ZenFone series.

On all other devices (that use different native libraries) it works without any issues. Did DJI not properly include these classes in the Intel Architecture libraries?

We declare the dependencies in the app build.gradle as follows:

```
dependencies {   
    implementation('com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9')
    compileOnly('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.9')
}
```

We would expect the proper resolution of these classes, but get the following errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/common/flightcontroller/CompassCalibrationState

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/common/flightcontroller/imu/SensorState;
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dji.common.flightcontroller.CompassCalibrationState" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.droneharmony.planner-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.droneharmony.planner-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.droneharmony.planner-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```